# *ngIf to evaluate an updated variable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular5

(Angular / JS learner) I have an object thats value gets updated via a service depending on which child controller is currently active.  I'm trying to get a different button to display based on this objects value.

My Parent Controller looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildDataService } from "../core/helpers/child-data.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childDetails: {title?: string};

  private subscription:Subscription;

  constructor( private childDataService: ChildDataService) {
    this.childDataService.childLoaded$.subscribe(
      newChildDetails => {
        console.log(newChildDetails);
        this.childDetails = newChildDetails
      });
  }
  someFunction(){};

  someFunction2(){};
}
```

And the relevant part of my parents HTML looks like:

```
<div class="subheader">
  <h1>{{ childDetails.title }}</h1>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails.title == 'dashboard'" (click)="someFunction()">dashboard</button>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails.title == 'page2'" (click)="someFunction2()">page2</button>
</div>
```

This throws the error: "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".  My service is working as intended as if I remove the 2 buttons the title  works.  A point in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a safe navigation operator

```
<div class="subheader">
  <h1>{{ childDetails?.title }}</h1>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails?.title == 'dashboard'" (click)="someFunction()">dashboard</button>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails?.title == 'page2'" (click)="someFunction2()">page2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.Although presented a new one.  My routerLink needs a second click to change the button.  Shall persevere to find out why ;) . cheers